Are cookies on *.run.app shared on other run.app subdomains?
If we go to Vercel's answer to this, they specifically mentioned:

vercel.app is under the public suffix list for security purposes and
as described in Wikipedia, one of it’s uses is to avoid supercookies.
These are cookies with an origin set at the top-level or apex domain
such as vercel.app. If an attacker in control of a Vercel project
subdomain website sets up a supercookie, it can disrupt any site at
the level of vercel.app or below such as anotherproject.vercel.app.
Therefore, for your own security, it is not possible to set a cookie
at the level of vercel.app from your project subdomain.

Does cloud run has a similar mechanism for *.run.app?
